# Web API 404 on content delivery server

Tags: azure, webapi, content-delivery

I am using Sitecore on azure and have a CD and a CM server.

The Web API works fine on CM but throws a 404 error (and no more information in logs).

I have deleted the following `dll` files from server as recommended in Sitecore documentation,

```
Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.dll
Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.dll
Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.ReAggregation.dll
```

I found a line in the `Sitecore.config` that might be helpful but refers to a file I cannot find on any server,

```
<handler trigger="~/api/" handler="sitecore_api.ashx" />
```

To go further into my research of the source of the problem, I would need to know if the web API feature is linked to a particular `dll` or `config file` I can investigate, or even the fix if someone has already encountered the problem.

Comment: can you try to enable   Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.config on CD just for test  ? are you web api calls starting with /api/sitecore/ ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber, enabling the Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.config did the trick. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I will change my comment into an answer. I will give you some details, is not a good practice to enable that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to enable Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.Config file .

In the Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.config file, the InitializeCommandRoute processor maps the /api/sitecore/{controller}/{action} route for SPEAK UI Applications, which are used by Sitecore Content Management installation. Probably your ajax call are using /api/sitecore.

If there is not a specific reason why your AJAX calls start with /api/sitecore/ prefix, please register a custom route using the standard ASP.NET MVC approach through Initialize pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem today while working on a function via sitecore api which is hosted in sitecore azure paas project. Hence, just to share. I have created the following:

**JS file**

```
<script>
    function showDiv() {
        var email = $("#email_id").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Accounts/GetEmailAddress",
            data: { "email": email },
            success: function (r) {
                if (r.trim().length > 0) {
                    document.getElementById('cta-thankyou').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('cta').style.display = "none";
                }
            }, error: function (error) {
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**RegisterWebApiRoutes.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Accounts.Infrastructure.Pipelines
{
    public class RegisterWebApiRoutes
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("PROJECTABC.Feature.Accounts.Api", "api/Accounts/{action}", new
            {
                controller = "Accounts"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**App_Config\Include\Feature\PROJECTABC.Feature.Accounts.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="PROJECTABC.Feature.Accounts.Infrastructure.Pipelines.RegisterWebApiRoutes, PROJECTABC.Feature.Accounts" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true" />
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```